# What is the Google Chrome Native Client?

Tags: google-chrome

What is the [Google Chrome Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/)?

> Native Client is an open-source technology that allows you to **build
>   web applications** that seamlessly execute native compiled code inside
>   the browser. This Google Code project is for maintaining the Native
>   Client implementation, including compiler and browser support. If
>   you're writing a compiler, are interested in porting Native Client to
>   a new browser, or are researching the security mechanisms underlying
>   Native Client, you can find useful resources in this project.

Does that mean that if I do not build web applications, I will have it disabled? Or will it actually make my browsing experience faster or something else that gives me some benefits?

Comment: What you are looking at is (mostly) a suite of developer tools. Chrome only supports the execution of native code. If you don't know what it is, and if you don't build web applications (as the text says), you don't need to download or install anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Native Client allows web applications to send C programs to your browser to be executed locally, with strong security controls. It's an advanced and experimental system that is not currently implemented by any web applications, to my knowledge. Any web application that does require it should make that clear. So, you can safely disable it.

Comment: You don't count [Quake](http://nacl-quake.appspot.com/) a web-application?